# Adding logic to 'find' directories containing either [criteria A] or [criteria B]

Tags: macos, bash, find

I have inherited a vast media archive without a unifying organizational scheme. Its contents date back at least 10 years. I have been asked to find a needle in this hay stack, and I have some guesses as to that needle's name.

But I don't know its name for certain. I want to use a single `find` command in the Terminal to search for alternate names. And I want to include a second set: possible file extensions.

In pseudocode, here's what I mean:

`find [in a given directory] [files and folders whose name matches (*guess1* OR *guess2*) AND whose name matches (*.extension1 OR *.extension2)]`.

How should I express this in the Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

`find` [has operators for this](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Combining-Primaries-With-Operators)*, and you can also group them for precedence:

```
find /some/path \
\( -name "*guess1*" -or -name "*guess2*" \) \
-and \
\( -name "*.extension1" -or -name "*.extension2" \)
```

Here, I just escaped newlines to make it easier to read, and I escaped the parentheses, since they may have special meaning to the shell.

<sub>* Note that the above manual is for GNU `find`, which is not shipped with OS X by default (but can be installed through [`brew install findutils`](http://brew.sh/)). The syntax is the same though.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Learning terminal find is very useful when I go between MacOS and Linux.

But when I am in MacOS and helping someone else find a file/folder I do not want to mention using terminal.

A free, fast and flexible solution is EasyFind http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html